# deleting all zip files in target directory and only keeping latest two zip files

Tags: java, file

I have developed an application which move file from source directory to target directory
by using apache Fileutils class methods as shown below..

```
private void filemove(String FilePath2, String s2) { 

        String filetomove = FilePath2 + s2;    //file to move its complete path
        File f = new File(filetomove);
        File d = new File(targetFilePath); //    path of target directory 
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(f, d);
            f.delete(); //from source dirrectory we are deleting the file if it succesfully move
        //*********** code need to add to delete the zip files of target directory and only keeping the latest two zip files  ************//        
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String errorMessage =  e.getMessage();
            logger.error(errorMessage);

        }

    }
```

Now  when I moving the file to the target directory , so in that case the target directory will be having certain zip files now these zip files in the target directory is being created by some other job which runs some process to create zip files , but any how what I am trying is that when ever I move my file to target directory so before keeping in target directory it should check the target directory and should delete the zip files at the same time it should ensure that only  two latest zip files it should not delete so at last the target directory should have my file which I am moving and latest two zip files please advise how to achieve this .

SO please advise the login which when it move the file to target directory it should delete all the zip files of the target directory keeping only recent two zip files only

folks please advise

Comment: Please format the question to be a bit more structured and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Not a optimized one but you can use.

```
    String[] extensions = {"zip","rar"};
    Collection<File> fileList = listFiles(FilePath2,extensions,false);
    File[] fileArray = new File[fileList.size()];

    int x = 0;
    for (Iterator iterator = fileList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        fileArray[x] = (File) iterator.next();
        x++;
    }

    File temp;

    for(int i=1; i< fileArray.length ; i++) {

        for(int j=0; j<fileArray.length-1; j++) {
            if(fileArray[j].lastModified() > fileArray[j+1].lastModified()) {
                 temp = fileArray [j];
                 fileArray [j] = fileArray [j+1];
                 fileArray [j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i< fileArray.length-2 ; i++) {
        deleteQuietly(fileArray[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take all the files in an array, and sort them, then just ignore the first two:

```
Comparator<File> fileDateComparator = new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        if(null == o1 || null == o2){
            return 0;
        }
        return (int) (o2.lastModified() - o1.lastModified());//yes, casting to an int. I'm assuming the difference will be small enough to fit.
    }
};

File f = new File("/tmp");
if (f.isDirectory()) {
    final File[] files = f.listFiles();
    List<File> fileList = Arrays.asList(files);
    Collections.sort(fileList, fileDateComparator);
    System.out.println(fileList);
}
```